# Структура данных для построения дерева графов

Tags: python, графы, дерево

Всем, привет! Имеется множество коммутаторов на которых настроен протокол LLDP. Данные о соседях известны(с кого порта включен сосед):

```
sw_1 на порту 26 подключен sw_2
sw_2 на порту 26 подключен sw_3
и  т.д.
```

Как из выше показанных данных собрать данных для построения дерево графов?

Comment: А что такое "дерево графов"? Без таких умных слов нельзя объяснить, чего же Вам надо-то?

Comment: Нужно получить вот такой результат http://xgu.ru/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB:Lldp2dot.png

Comment: Если нужно только построить граф, а питон тут так, то рекомендую изучить такую штуку как graphviz. На питоне составите текстовый файл вида

    digraph x {
      "sw_1:26" -> "sw_2";
      "sw_2:26" -> "sw_3";
    }

потом запускаете команду dot или netty и передаете ей этот файл

    dot x.dot -Tpng > x.png

и все.

Изучите синтаксис глубже - сможете делать с графом все что угодно. Для особых ценителей можно сохранить в svg и потом открыть в corel/inskape и отредактировать.

Comment: @KoVadim там и для виндов вроде дистрибутив был.

@avdoshkin А что такое Lldp2dot (dot, как уже отметил @KoVadim -- язык graphviz), а вот кто это преобразование делает? И нет ли этого самого lldp2dot у Вас на диске?

Comment: библиотечки tulip быстрее и качественне graphviz

Comment: @eicto этот самый Тульпан, по описанию, для больших графьёв, а у @avdoshkin "множество" вряд ли такое большое. Тем более, tulip -- новое решение, а Lldp2dot -- уже работающее.

Comment: Lldp2dot - это решение не мое и как оно работает и разбираться сильно не хочется. В какое направления копать понятно. Спасибо, всем!

Comment: Как можно убрать дублирующие записи:

    sw1 sw2
    sw2 sw1
    sw1 sw3

из этого нужно убрать строку sw2 sw1. Данные можно собрать в любой тип, перед тем как искать дубли.

Comment: получить уникальные элементы просто. Самый простой (но не самый эффективный) способ - преобразовываете все в список строк, а потом через set. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897374/get-unique-values-from-a-list-in-python).

Comment: set(list) хорошо, но не в моем случае. У меня список всех устройств в цикле прохожу по всем устройств получаю пару вершин к примеру:

    sw1 sw2 (к sw1 подключен sw2)
    sw2 sw1 (к sw2 подключен sw1)

Если нарисовать дерево графа то получим пару вершин с двумя ребрами, вообщем получили кольцо, но фактически одно ребро. set(list) применять не могу т.к. к sw1 может подключен еще пару устройств.

Comment: ну так в чем проблема - эти строки разные. Значит set(list) их не удалит.

Comment: @avdoshkin, если у Вас во всех строках по два слова, то для начала просто отсортируйте эти слова в алфавитном порядке.

Например, на sh это может выглядеть так

    #!/bin/sh
    while read s1 s2 
    do
      if [ "$s1" '<' "$s2" ] ; then
        echo $s1 $s2
      else
        echo $s2 $s1
      fi
    done | sort -u | dot какие-то-ее параметры

в предположении, что команда `dot` может брать данные со стандартного ввода (обычное для \*nix поведение).